# How to calculate an error in a function?

Tags: error-propagation

I have this function :
T= (R1+R2-R12)/(2*R1*R2) and I want to calculate the error in T?
So What is the general principle in calculating the error or uncertainty in a function of several variables ?

Comment: The *general* principle is that the error in a function of several variables is approximately the sum of the absolute values of all the partial derivatives, each multiplied by the corresponding errors. So for example the error in $xy$ is approximately $|y| \Delta x + |x| \Delta y$ where $\Delta x,\Delta y$ are the uncertainties in $x$ and $y$ respectively. Physics classes often teach some special cases of this without teaching the general principle (to avoid teaching students about derivatives, I guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you have to use logarithmic derivative.

$\frac{dT}{T}=\frac{d(R_1+R_2+R_3)}{R_1+R_2+R_3}-\frac{dR_1}{R_1}-\frac{dR_2}{R_2}$

which gives the relative error

$dT=T.(    \frac{dR_1+dR_2+dR_3}{R_1+R_2+R_3}-\frac{ dR_1}{R_1}-\frac{  dR_2}{R_2})$

then you replace for example $dR_1$ by 
 your error at $R_1$, $\delta R_1$ and signum $-$ by $+$ to obtain an upper bound.

Comment: A warning: depending on the specifics of your model, errors in independent variables which are being summed may not simply add. For example one model is that errors in independent variables are each independent Gaussians, and standard deviations of independent Gaussians do not add when the Gaussians are added. The "standard physics error propagation" that I was taught was based on this model (so that for example the $\Delta(x+y)=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$).